# angularjs ng-show not working when ng-click

Tags: angularjs

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="personnes">
    <div infinite-scroll='RedditUsers.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-disabled='RedditUsers.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='3'  >
        <div class="search-item row" ng-init="request=false" ng-repeat="user in RedditUsers.users" >
            <div class=" pull-left">
                <img ng-src="{{notif.subscriber.avatar == 'no_avatar' &&  '/images/default.svg' || 'http://localhost:85/api.immortality.life/application/uploads/avatars/'+user.id_user+'/'+user.avatar }}" class="edit-img">
                <span>{{user.first_name+' '+user.last_name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right" >


                <button ng-if="user.friend == null && request==false" ng-hide="request" ng-click="addFriend($event,user);request=true;" class="add-btn btn"><i class=" icon-friends s"></i>Ajouter</button>
                <span  ng-show="request" class="add-btn btn"><i class=" icon-friends s"></i>Demande envoyée</span>
                <span ng-if="user.friend != null " class="add-btn btn"><i class=" icon-friends s"></i></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show='RedditUsers.busy'>Loading data...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is when i click the button the first span dont show despite of i made ng-show="request"

Answer (score 0):

change your ng-click to:

```
ng-click="addFriend($event,user);setRequest(true);"
```

in your JS file

```
$scope.setRequest = setRequest;
function setRequest(val){
    $scope.request = val;
}
```

Comment: change $scope.apply() to $scope.$apply(). edited the answer

Comment: i got this error "angular.min.js:114 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply" 3 times(3=number of ng-repeat)

Comment: ng-click should automatically call the $scope.$apply(). Remove the last line and check.

Comment: remove the error but the same problem i think the problem is that the ng-click is just apply in the button because ng-hide in the button work

Comment: finally, it works :D the problem was ng-if remove the item from the dom and even the ng-click